# How to deal with equivalences in proofs?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms

There is a part I need clarification on regarding the use of equivalence and its symmetry.
From what I understand in regards to symmetry is that:
$ (p \equiv q) \equiv (q \equiv p) $. Given p and q are well formed formulas. Therefore: 
$((A\land B \equiv A \equiv B) \equiv (A \lor B)) \equiv ((A \lor B) \equiv (A\land B \equiv A \equiv B))$
Assuming  p = $(A\land B \equiv A \equiv B)$ and q = $(A\lor B)$.
We know that:
 $((A\land B \equiv A \equiv B) \equiv (A \lor B))$
is true since it is an axiom(golden rule). But does this mean
$((A \lor B) \equiv (A\land B \equiv A \equiv B))$
is a valid as a corollary since it is equivalent?
I know by common sense that the disjunction of A and B is not equivalent to its conjunction and likewise A or B but I don't know  where the flaw is in the given pattern of thinking.

Comment: The corollary doesn't say that the disjunction is equivalent to the conjunction, any more than the earlier statements do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The so-called **Golden Rule** is "typical" of [Equational Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic); thus I'll assume that your question must be "interpreted" in this context.

I'll refer to the textbook by George Tourlakis, [Mathematical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470280743) (2008), which is devoted to the exposition of mathematical logic according to the "equational" style.

The *axioms* of the system are listed at page 42-43, and include the **Golden Rule** :

> > $A \land B \equiv A \equiv B \equiv A \lor B$.

Clearly, an axiom must be a *tautology*.

But we know that $A \land B, A \equiv B$ and $A \lor B$ are **not** equivalent, while

> $(A \land B) \equiv (A \equiv B) \equiv (A \lor B)$

is a *tautology*.

*So, where is the "trick" ?*

What is the "utility" of the above "equation" if its "sub-formulae" are not equivalent ?

The "trick" is in the parentheses; the axiom as stated in Tourlakis' book is without parentheses. If we want to restore them, we must follow a rule.

We have [see page 15] the following rule regarding the *priority* (or *precedence*) between connectives :

> Higher-priority connectives bind before lower-priority ones. That is [...] the higher-priority connective "glues" first.
>
> The order of priorities (decreasing from left to right) is agreed to be :
>
> > $\lnot, \land, \lor, \rightarrow, \equiv$.

We must also note the comment in footnote 48 [page 42] : "Recall that brackets associate from right to left".

Now, if we want to restore the parentheses into the **Golden Rule**, we must reintroduce them consistently : $\land$ and $\lor$ have higher-priority.

Thus, they "glue" first, and the formula becomes :

> $(A \land B) \equiv A \equiv B \equiv (A \lor B)$.

But all the occurrences of $\equiv$ have obviously the same priority; thus, we must insert parentheses from right to left, with the result :

> > $(A \land B) \equiv (A \equiv B \equiv (A \lor B))$.

As you can easily verify, this **is** a *tautology*.

When $(A \equiv B)$ has the same value of $(A \lor B)$ ? Only when both $A$ and $B$ are *true*; i.e. exactly when $(A \land B)$ hodls.

But it does **not** assert that $A \land B$ is equivalent to $A \lor B$, nor to $A \equiv B$.

Of course, $\equiv$ **is** *symmetric*; thus, the above formula is equivalent to : $(A \equiv B \equiv (A \lor B))\equiv (A \land B)$.

But we can also "permute" the subformulae; when $(A \land B)$ has the same value of $(A \lor B)$ ? When $A$ and $B$ are both *true* or both *false*; i.e. when $(A \equiv B)$ hodls. Thus, we have also :

> $((A \lor B) \equiv (A \land B)) \equiv (A \equiv B)$.

We must note that in the context of equational logic a *derivation* is basically a chain of equivalences. The axioms must be used "in collaboration" with the *rules of inference* [see page 40] which include *Equanimity* [an "equational" form of *detachement rule*] :

> from $A$ and $A \equiv B$, derive $B$.

---

*Note*

The "equational" style looks different from the traditional exposition of mathematical logic, but it "works" basically in the same way.

See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd - 2001), page 33 : the priority rules for connectives are the same and when one connective symbol is used repeatedly, the convention for grouping is to the right.

Comment: I thought more of equivalential calculus than equational logic when reading this question.  Equivalential calculi often have a rule of "equanimity" as the only deduction rule other than uniform substitution.

Answer (score 0):

"We know that:
((A∧B≡A≡B)≡(A∨B))
is true since it is an axiom(golden rule). But does this mean
((A∨B)≡(A∧B≡A≡B))
is a valid as a corollary since it is equivalent?"

Yes.  A quick way to verify this comes as to look at the truth table for ≡.

```
 ≡      False   True
False   True    False
True    False   True
```

Now suppose that (p≡q) is true and "p" is true also.  p as true corresponds to the second row of the truth table.  (p≡q) as true corresponds to the (false, false) position and the (true, true) position of the truth table.  So, (p≡q) as true and "p" as true overlap in the lower right hand quadrant of the truth table.  In this case, q is true also.  Consequently, it follows that if (p≡q) is true, and if "p" is true also, then "q" is also true.

Now, you know that [(a≡b)≡(b≡a)] is a tautology.  It follows that if you have any axiom or theorem of the form (p≡q) which is a tautology, (q≡p) can get deduced also.